# Modify query for a better performance when working with large sets of data

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph with lots of duplicate relationships, on a sample data I have a query which counts the duplicates edges creates a new relationship with the count as weight. When I apply that query to the whole data set, the Neo4j is crashing.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (u:Disease)-[r:HAS_CHILD]->(o:Disease) 
WITH u,o,count(r) AS count 
CREATE (u)-[r:HAS_CHILD{weight:count}]->(o) 
RETURN u,r,o;
```

This query works and does exactly what I need but is not working on a large data set. Is there a way to improve this query performance? Or is there another way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `OPTIONAL` modifier.

For your use case, it makes no sense to match nonexistent relationships, and you should not try to create relationships with `null` end nodes.